# how to encode my input string since I have build a Huffman tree and character corresponding code by C

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list, tree, huffman-code

**this code now can be compiled, but only output the table of code and the minimum weighted external path length**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_TREE_HT 100

struct MinHeapNode {
    char data;
    unsigned freq;
    struct MinHeapNode *left, *right;
};

struct MinHeap {
    unsigned size;
    unsigned capacity;
    struct MinHeapNode** array;
};

struct MinHeapNode* newNode(char data, unsigned freq) {
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = (struct MinHeapNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode));
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->freq = freq;

    return temp;
}

struct MinHeap* createMinHeap(unsigned capacity) {
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = (struct MinHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));
    minHeap->size = 0;
    minHeap->capacity = capacity;
    minHeap->array = (struct MinHeapNode**)malloc(minHeap->capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*));

    return minHeap;
}

void swapMinHeapNode(struct MinHeapNode** a,
                     struct MinHeapNode** b) {
    struct MinHeapNode* t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}

void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx) {
    int smallest = idx;
    int left = 2 * idx + 1;
    int right = 2 * idx + 2;

    if (left < minHeap->size && 
        minHeap->array[left]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = left;

    if (right < minHeap->size && 
        minHeap->array[right]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = right;

    if (smallest != idx) {
        swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest],
                        &minHeap->array[idx]);
        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
    }
}

int isSizeOne(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    return (minHeap->size == 1);
}

struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = minHeap->array[0];
    minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];

    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);

    return temp;
}

void insertMinHeap(struct MinHeap* minHeap,
                   struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode) {
    ++minHeap->size;
    int i = minHeap->size - 1;

    while (i && minHeapNode->freq < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->freq) {
        minHeap->array[i] = minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2];
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }

    minHeap->array[i] = minHeapNode;
}

void buildMinHeap(struct MinHeap* minHeap) {
    int n = minHeap->size - 1;
    int i;

    for (i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
        minHeapify(minHeap, i);
}

void printArr(int arr[], int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

**here I want to make a function to encode the input string ,can anyone help?**

```
void encode(struct MinHeapNode* root, int arr[], int n) {

}

int isLeaf(struct MinHeapNode* root) {
    return !(root->left) && !(root->right);
}

struct MinHeap* createAndBuildMinHeap(char data[], int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        minHeap->array[i] = newNode(data[i], freq[i]);

    minHeap->size = size;
    buildMinHeap(minHeap);

    return minHeap;
}

struct MinHeapNode* buildHuffmanTree(char data[],int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeapNode *left, *right, *top;

    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createAndBuildMinHeap(data, freq, size);

    while (!isSizeOne(minHeap)) {
        left = extractMin(minHeap);
        right = extractMin(minHeap);
        top = newNode('$', left->freq + right->freq);

        top->left = left;
        top->right = right;

        insertMinHeap(minHeap, top);
    }

    return extractMin(minHeap);
}

void printCodes(struct MinHeapNode* root, int arr[], int top) {
    if (root->left) {
        arr[top] = 0;
        printCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1);
    }

    if (root->right) {
        arr[top] = 1;
        printCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1);
    }

    if (isLeaf(root)) {
        printf("%c:", root->data);
        printArr(arr, top);
    }
}

void HuffmanCodes(char data[], int freq[], int size) {
    struct MinHeapNode* root = buildHuffmanTree(data, freq, size);

    int arr[MAX_TREE_HT], top = 0;

    printCodes(root,arr,top);
}

int main() {
    char input;
    int i = 0;
    char plaintext[20];
    int counta = 0, countb = 0, countc = 0;

    while (scanf("%c", &input) != EOF) {
        if (input == 'a') {
            plaintext[i] = 'a';
            counta++;
        }

        if (input == 'b') {
            plaintext[i] = 'b';
            countb++; 
        }

        if (input == 'c') {
            plaintext[i] = 'c';
            countc++; 
        }

        i++;
    }

    char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int freq[] = {counta, countb, countc};

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    HuffmanCodes(arr, freq, size);

    int counting[3];
    counting[0] = counta;
    counting[1] = countb;
    counting[2] = countc;

    if (counting[0] < counting[1]) {
        int temp = counting[0];
        counting[0] = counting[1];
        counting[1] = temp;
    }

    if (counting[2] > counting[0]) {
        counting[0] = counting[2];
    }

    int sum = counting[0] * 1 + counting[1] * 2 + counting[2] * 2;
    printf("> %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

****I supposed to read the character code into an array but I don't know how to send input string into any function and get encoding****

**[image: sample input/output]**
**problem discription**

Comment: To encode a symbol, you locate the corresponding leaf node in the table, then traverse from that to the root, emitting the left/right bit that lead to the child. To do this, the nodes obviously need a parent link. The encoding generated this way will be back to front, so must be flipped before emitted. Since this whole process is relatively inefficient, it's common instead to just traverse the Huffman tree once and populate a lookup table with each symbol and its encoding and length, which is then used in the encoding process.